Double ratchet algorithm
I'm trying to find a description of the double ratchet algorithm written in the form of a cryptographic algorithm such as the example below; can anyone share any resources please?

Are you looking specifically for the double ratchet protocol used by Signal?

@aiootp yes, though how many variations of double rather protocols are out there?

It's just that one can imagine many systems that can be called a "Double Ratchet". Implementations of the Signal Protocol may also vary in the details.

From the paper A Formal Security Analysis of the Signal Messaging Protocol [CCDGS19], there are several diagrams depicting the protocol flow, as well as accompanying analyses.
Here's one such figure from the paper:


Yet another set of algorithm diagrams is given in The Double Ratchet: Security Notions, Proofs, and Modularization for the Signal Protocol [ACD20]:


I'd also be remiss not to include the work Formal Analysis of Session-Handling in Secure Messaging: Lifting Security from Sessions to Conversations [CJN23] which demonstrates attack algorithms, and formal prover program syntax, on the Post-Compromise Security of parts of Signal's implementation:

